# Installing tomcat on windows using CHEF

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, centos, chef-infra

I have an instance on amazon aws which is centos and working as chef workstation. Two nodes viz. centos and windows server 16 base are working as chef client on which I need to install tomcat server. Centos client is done but cant install tomcat on windows instance using different cookbook available on internet. Can someone please give some suggestions or any recipe to do the task. Thank you!!

Comment: What's the Chef recipe you're using? Are you seeing an error message saying why the installation didn't succeed?

Comment: I was making my own as well as trying from supermarket. There was no error only the default.rb was running without any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by writing the following code in the following files

**default.rb**:-
def run
    `C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/pocwin/recipes/tomins.bat`
end
puts run

You also have to install chocolatey package in your powershell and the write a .bat file as given below:-

**tomcat.bat**:-
choco install tomcat -y

put all these files in a recipes and upload it on the chef windows client and run **chef-client**